# CakePHP routing: forward / and /index

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, url-routing

I've discovered an odd problem. I run website.com. (for this example)

If I visit website.com/play, all my links are just fine. If I visit website.com/play/ or play/index, all the links suddenly break.

I build all my URLs using `this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'whatever', 'action' => 'whatever'));`

I'm wondering how I could make it so that someone could visit website.com/play/ or website.com/play/index and have it forwarded over to website.com/play. This should be without javascript. I can't seem to figure out if CakePHP's routing does this, but I'm nearly certain it does.

Writing `Router::connect('/play/', array('controller' => 'plays'));` did not help.

**UPDATE**

Looking around the internet, I found it suggested for CakePHP to simply reroute with .htaccess. [This answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081478/547489)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

- The better way is to have the links checked out.
- Is the controller called `Play` or `Plays`? Are you accessing `/play` or `/plays`?
- Are you creating links this way? `echo $this->Html->link('Add User', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add'));`
- Can you paste an example of an incorrect link you get on /play/, and how it was created?

Comment: The links are all built with $this->Html->url() and the controller is plays, with a route I created for "/play". I updated my question with my solution. Thanks.