# .htaccess rewrit rule remove trailing slash if not directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are many similar questions like this,but I don't understand  `rewriterule`.

I have a php file ,like the following

```
switch($_GET['p']){
    case"home":
        echo"<a href='sport'>sport</a>";

        switch($_GET['a']){
            case"sport":
                echo"This is sport";
            break;
            }
        break;
    }
```

I want if access sport case, like

```
tes/category/sport
```

NB: tes, is directory of my php file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Htaccess trailing slash that's had me stumped for days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-trailing-slash-thats-had-me-stumped-for-days)

Comment: but i dont understand, please explain it

Comment: Don't ask me, ask the guy who answered the other question.

Comment: Unable to understand your problem, can you clarify it again.