# remove trailing slash from URL in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my htaccess configured to work in conjunction with a URL Router I've written in PHP.  I'm trying to remove a trailing slash if seen from the URL except the root url.  My htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My URLs look like this:

```
http://my-site-domain.com/login
```

This works great but a trailing slashe is causing some issues. (e.g.)

```
http://my-site-domain.com/login/
```

Any idea how I can remove the trailing slash for params passed in but not for the root URL?

Thanks,
-Paul

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264788/1066234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: That did the trick...I assume the R is redirect but what is 302, NE, and L?

Comment: 302 is for http status code = 302 used in redirect. L is for last and NE for no encoding. More details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score -1):

For those who are still running into this problem, I solved mine by adding a question mark just after the slash before the dollar sign, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```