# Prevent redirect of "path" to "path/" in apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I'm using XAMPP to create a local server and noticed that when I visit something like **localhost/path** I get redirected (301) to **localhost/path/**

The problem is that I'm trying to send a **POST** request to **localhost/path** and after being redirected it turns into a **GET** request.

Is there a way to prevent such redirect from happening?

It may be worth mentioning that I'm using **mod_rewrite** in a **.htaccess** file, but even with all the rules disabled the behaviour remains the same.

### Edit

I realized that I had a folder called **path** and renaming it prevented **localhost/path** from redirecting.

Still, is there a way to avoid such behivour (not getting a 301 to **localhost/path/**) when the folder exists with the same name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove trailing slash from URL in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916464/remove-trailing-slash-from-url-in-htaccess)

Comment: I'm afraid it does not.

Comment: Edited the original post with a partial solution I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `DirectorySlash` directive and a regular regex that removes the trailing slashes:

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectorySlash Off
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

**Example:** Assumig that `path` is an existing folder and `foo` doesn't exist:

- `/path/` => `/path`
- `/path/foo/` => `/path/foo`
- `/foo/` => `/foo`
- `/path` stays the same
- `/path/foo` stays the same
- `/foo` stays the same