# htaccess redirection wired issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have HTML website hosted under Apache. Following htaccess added to redirect all the `http` calls to `https` and hide the extension from URL.
I have following pages in it

```
Home page - example.com <- index.html
About  - example.com/about <- about.html
Contact - example.com/contact <- contact.html
404 - example.com/404 <- 404.html
```

htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404.html
```

But if we call a page directly as `https://example.com/contact.html` this will render with .html extension itself(same as example.com/contact.html), it supposed to be https://www.example.com/contact.

Anyone can help to solve this confusion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove php extension and also redirect extensions to no extension form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021181/how-to-remove-php-extension-and-also-redirect-extensions-to-no-extension-form)

Comment: This `htaccess` code should work as expected. Clear your browser cache and try again.