# RewriteURL generic solution for all URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have marked my Previous Question as duplicate But I am getting Problem after testing the existing solutions ..I am posting what I have tried further ..

I am trying to remove trailing slash in every incoming request URL

I Searched and studied other posts including this

[Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

and  Based on existing Answers I Wrote htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

this rewrites my URL from

```
http://localhost/WCOM/Flatsome/blog/
```

to

```
http://localhost/blog
```

I Tried another htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

This rewrites URL

from

```
http://localhost/WCOM/Flatsome/blog/
```

to

```
http://localhost/WCOM/Flatsome/blog.htm
```

I am much satisfied with later htaccess code But I want to remove extension keeping removed slash .. How can it be done ??

Comment: I rectified my post . it is giving same error

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.htm [L]
```

Comment: Your answer has this rule "RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]"  .. it was not working for me ... Ineed to change it to "RewriteRule (.*) /$1.htm [L]"

Comment: this rule is removing /  from My URL ... resulting URL I am getting is " http://localhost/WCOM/Flatsome/blog "