# Laravel 5 bad behaviour while removing trailing slash

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a Laravel project under *mywebsite.com/laravel/*. When I go to *mywebsite.com/laravel/test*, everything is ok, but when I go to *mywebsite.com/laravel/test/*, I'm redirected to *mywebsite.com/test*.

I have the files *index.php* and *.htaccess* in my */laravel* directory. This is my *.htaccess* file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteBase /laravel
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I have no idea why `RewriteBase` doesn't work. I've tried */laravel*, */laravel/* and *laravel*; nothing worked.

My routes.php file

```
<?php
Route::get('/test/{name?}', 'MainController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

Comment: The code works fine from my tests in every way.  Technically, with how you've written the rule, you shouldn't even need the RewriteBase because the rule will include the entire URI and just strip the last /.

Comment: I've tested it on localhost and on hosting server, in both cases it redirects me to domain.com/test, I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Wolen Please, share your `route.php`

Comment: @Wolen Don't post in answer. Edit your question. At the bottom of your question add the code of your route.

Comment: @smartrahat oh, sorry, I have corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

And in my case clear cache in my browser :).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me; removing all trailing slashes from all routes while emphasizing that REQUEST_URI starts with a slash (at least in .htaccess files):

Replace:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

With:

```
# Remove all trailing slashes    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

This will rewrite **mywebsite.com/laravel/test/** to **mywebsite.com/laravel/test/** without redirecting you ***mywebsite.com/test***

Just **don't use** `%{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$`. Because in the root directory REQUEST_URI equals /, the leading slash, and it would be misinterpreted as a trailing slash.

**SOURCE:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264788/2732184