# URL with ending slash throws NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen, lumen-5.4

I am using Laravel Lumen microframework v5.4.6

When trying to load page `http://lumen.dev/dax30` everything works fine, but when I request page `http://lumen.dev/dax30/` (with ending slash (`/`) at the URL end) I receive a *NotFoundHttpException* error.

My routes.php file:

```
$_app = $this->app;
$_app->group(['prefix' => 'dax30'], function () use ($_app){
    $_app->get('/', 'Landings\Dax30\Controllers\IndexController@index');
});
```

Question: How to open this page with and without slash with no error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Laravel consider both as different routes, although you can resolve this issue by changing your .htaccess file. Please have a look at this answer 
[Laravel 5 bad behaviour while removing trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441338/laravel-5-bad-behaviour-while-removing-trailing-slash)