# .htaccess file - remove trailing slash form all url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am working on an .htaccess rule.

I want to remove trailing slash form all url.

```
        For ex:- 
        http://www.test.com/admin    Working fine
        But
        http://www.test.com/admin/   Gives me error.
```

If I run URL like http://www.test.com/admin/dashboard/
then its auomatically redirect to http://www.test.com/admin/dashboard

I have put below code in htaccess file.

```
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

But its redirect like this.

http://www.test.com/var/www/html/test/public/admin

Comment: Seems duplicate. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url

Comment: Thanks for quick response..Its work as charm

Comment: https://helponnet.com/2020/02/20/how-to-remove-traling-slashes-from-urls-using-rewriterule-url-rewriting-tips/

Answer (score 0):

Origianl answer - [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Right below the RewriteEngine On line, add:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to enforce a no-trailing-slash policy.

To enforce a trailing-slash policy:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```