# Why my PHP site is not working with Slash in browser?

Tags: php, web

One of my client site is opening is wrong format when we use slash(/) in browse.
 Without slash its working fine...I don't why slash(/) is not working in my site???

For Example :-

1. http://www.future-secure.com/about.php/
2. http://www.future-secure.com/about.php

Both are opening is different format. why? I like 2nd one.

Comment: Refer this link https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Comment: Thanks for help but i fix this issue from another thread...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url

Answer (score 1):

"/" basically is used to access a folder or a directory

```
 Example www.abc.com/aa/index.php
```

So its preferred no use "/" after file name unless you to want to target to specific portions or section of a website

```
Example www.abc.com/index.php/#div_id
```