# mod_rewrite sometime adds DocumentRoot path to url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My DocumentRoot is **var/www/public**

I've following .htaccess file (inside **var/www/public**):

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I enter for example `http://localhost:8080/en/schedule/` it works fine - redirects to url without trailing slash (`http://localhost:8080/en/schedule`)

But there are cases when it not works well:

`http://localhost:8080/en/news/` redirects to `http://localhost:8080/var/www/public/en/news`

Comment: Does /en/news exist ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: Yes, exists. I've solved it already (see my answer), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different behaviour for different links was caused by web browser cache.

New .htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```