# htaccess url rewriting: adding trailing slash does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Unfortunately I have a problem where I get stuck.

I would add behind each URL a trailing slash and then redirect the version without a slash via 301 to the variant with a slash.

Previously, i have the html file extension with url rewriting successfully removed and SSL enforced.

So, i tried the following code to add a slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I have found this solution, on this thread: [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

It remains unfortunately ineffective.

Interestingly, when I, for example, visits the following URL (with a slash at the end):

example.com/imprint/

I get the following message: The requested URL was not found **/imprint.html/** on this server.

imprint.html???

Here is my complete .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Activate and force ssl and redirect from non-www to www#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Removes HTMl-Extension and make URLs clean# 

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect Index Files e.g. /index or /index.html
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#Adds a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I hope, you can help me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you check `!-f` (not a file) it will skip `.html` files also. You can use `[OR]`

```
RewriteEngine On

#Activate and force ssl and redirect from non-www to www#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#Redirect Index Files e.g. /index or /index.html
RewriteRule ^index\.html/?$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/index\.html/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NE,NE]

#Adds a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301,NE]

#Removes HTMl-Extension and make URLs clean# 

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank You, but that does not work. :-( Same Error example.com/imprint says: 404 - example.com/imprint.html/ was not foud.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work for me. No changes and just a 404. :<

Comment: try my updated answer now. Also tell what URL are you using to test?