# http redirect with htaccess updating url only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

working with .htaccess i solved about the url conversion from (for example):

(a) http://www.mydomain.ext/dir/myfile.php

to:

(b) http://www.mydomain.ext/dir/myfile

(deleting the .php) to end. But if user from web typing as in (a) them display the url so as typed. 
How i can solve becouse typing as in (a) webserver display too as in (b) ? 
I thinked about a redirect from (a) to (b) but not think that it is the best solution, what suggest for solve it?
Thanks very much for help.

---

ADD THIS:
Try to explain better the question with a concrete example. Starting from .htaccess i have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

and i solved it using PHP so:

```
$default_url = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER

["REQUEST_URI"]; // display something as: http://www.mysite.ext/dir/filename.php
    $canonical_url = str_replace(".php", "", "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); // display something as: http://www.mysite.ext/dir/filename
    if ( $default_url != $canonical_url ) {
        header( 'Location: ' . $canonical_url, true, 301 );
    }
```

I ask as update the .htaccess code for integrate about feature descripted in PHP script. I have looked much example but not solve it.
Thanks very much.

Comment: https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks for link, looking about post if type url as in (a) the webpage load correctly and in browser i display as in (a). When i type url as in (b) the webpage load correctly and i display as in (b). 
I want solve about this problem: if i type as in (a) i want display as in (b). It of course in url field of the browser. I hope to have explained better now with example.

Comment: @anubhava , my problem not is allow to a web page to be loaded without *.php extension from url (i have solved it. I told it in my post). My problem is other, When i type a url putting *.php extension the page is loaded (as same url without *.php) but into field URL of the browser remain the URL having *.PHP extension. I want just to do in mode which typing something as: http://www.pippo.it/page.php  in the browser where is URL displayed, i have : http://www.pippo.it/page. Solution is a reload page with a redirect to: http://www.pippo.it/page but how i need to do it with htaccess? Thanks.

Comment: PS: In this sense i don't see this topic as a duplicate, becouse it, yes allow to load page without *.PHP but not remove it from URL displayed on the browser.

Comment: @anubhava i have looked where you suggest me, i have tried but not work. In my post i have added an example concrete, can look better my example so you can understand better about what i want to do? Thanks again.

Comment: @anubhava i looked about htaccess for externally redirect, i have tried to add that line into htaccess (removing php code, of course) and check, but not work. My problem is this. My htaccess is places in root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert my comments into an answer, have these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Ok thanks very much. So work fine! I don't want abuse of your patience, but can i ask you a last things? When source url point to directory (eg. http://www.mydomain.ext/mydir) i get something as: http://www.mydomain.ext/mydir/ so i ask you as i can clean last character and to have: http://www.mydomain.ext/mydir only. I have searched here about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url  but not helped me much, can tell me better as i can solve? Thanks again very much.

Comment: If URL is pointing to a directory then you must keep trailing slash in the end for security reasons. That's the reason Apache's `mod_dir` module automatically adds a trailing slash for directory URLs.

Comment: To elaborate further, [read this official documentation on `mod_dir`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) and do read **Security Warning**.