# removing forward slash from my website url

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, .htaccess

How to i remove the forward slash from the url of my website.

I have a simple website in php, which runs on linux with apache webserver. It does not uses any complex script etc. But when-ever i type the url http://www.example.com it is converted to http://www.example.com/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R]
```

Comment: Change $1/ to just $1 in the RewriteRule?

Comment: try changing `$1/` to `$1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url

Comment: `http://www.example.com/` and `http://www.example.com` are same. `/` in the end is being added by the browser itself.

Comment: i know that but i want to remove the slash using .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1 [R]`

The `$1/` in the last line means the server should handle it as `example.com/request-filename/`, not like `example.com/request-filename`,
which is  achieved by just the $1

Comment: not  working.placed the .htaccess  file in the website root folder and LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is enabled in apache conf

Comment: does it still convert to example.com/, or is there an error?

Comment: it still convert to example.com/