# nginx rewrite html file and add trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have read a dozen rewite questions. Most questions are for .php but I have simple .html files so about => about.html .But I am not able to get nginx to do this:

- accept url with or without "/"
- redirect domain.com/about and domain.com/about/ to domain.com/about.html
- add trailing slash to the URL so if I write domain.com/about it writes domain.com/about/

I have tried with this code
`rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1.html;`
but it gives me 404 error on url ending with "/". Also tried this 
`rewrite ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ $1.html` with same error.

Some suggest I should be using try `try_files`?

I tried this also which gives a 500 error:

```
location / { 
rewrite ^(.*)$ /%1 redirect; 
rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html break; 
}
```

I tried to convert apache to nginx (winginx.com) from suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url?rq=1) with no success.

This code does not work. I am trying to redirect and add trailing slash:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
}
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/(.*[^/])$ /$1/ redirect;
}
```

Any suggestion would make me happy.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to rename `about.html` to `about/index.html` then `nginx` pretty much does what you want with its index module.

Comment: This sounds a bit overkill. Instead of single html files I would have to make a folder for every html file and put the contents in a index.html file into that folder?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this configuration and it appears to meet your requirements (YMMV):

```
root /path/to/root;

location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1.html break;
}
```

The first location attempts to serve the file *as is* which is necessary for resource files. Otherwise it defers to the named location.

The named location will permanently redirect any URIs which do not end in `/`. Otherwise, the `.html` file is served.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Hi, sorry this is not working. With this config I get a 404 page on index.html (root). When I click on e.g.  "projects" it shows projects.html and the URL is "http://example.com/projects/" but all css and images are broken.

On the page projects I click on link ***"about"*** (the page is about.html) and I get "http://example.com/projects/about/" -> It should be "http://example.com/about/" and from there it goes to "http://example.com/projects/about/about/about/ ...." etc. so there is an internal loop.

Comment: Using path relative resources (css & js) will not work with your scheme, as the browser assumes that the trailing `/` is a subdirectory. The link to `about.html` should probably be `/about.html` to avoid getting `/project/about.html` for the same reason. I don't get the internal loop - but it is a big risk with these types of scheme.

Comment: I agree with the risk Richard! I rewrote the paths to absolute and the css and images are working. Also made the links absolute. That fixed the wrong URLs . Thanks for the insight and for understanding what I was trying to solve!

Answer (score 0):

I think a try_files would be appropriate here. For example:

```
location /about {
    try_files about.html;
}
```

Comment: Will work for about.html but I have many files, about.html, contact.html, projects.html, gallery.html etc...

Comment: You can create a block for each one or use a regex like: `location ~ ^/(.*)/?$ {try_files $1.html;}`