# Rewriterule to redirect trailing slash to non-trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a website which is available on `medify.eu` and on `medify.eu/nl` for the Dutch language version. Currently, google is linking to `medify.eu/nl/` though (with a slash at the end), which gives an error, so I want to redirect `medify.eu/nl/` to `medify.eu/nl`.

My `.htaccess` looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.

    AddType audio/aac .aac
    AddType audio/mp4 .mp4 .m4a
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp1 .mp2 .mp3 .mpg .mpeg
    AddType audio/ogg .oga .ogg
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/webm .webm
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/ogg .ogv
    AddType video/webm .webm
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417551/1650012) I added two lines so that the whole file now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.

    ###### I ADDED THESE TWO LINESBELOW ######
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    AddType audio/aac .aac
    AddType audio/mp4 .mp4 .m4a
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp1 .mp2 .mp3 .mpg .mpeg
    AddType audio/ogg .oga .ogg
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/webm .webm
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/ogg .ogv
    AddType video/webm .webm
```

But it still doesn't redirect `medify.eu/nl/` to `medify.eu/nl`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a trailing slash using `.htaccess` you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this. After testing with your website, the output result:

[image: Removed Trailing Slash]

Comment: I've added your lines, but it still doesn't work (as you can see on https://medify.eu/nl/ ). Any other ideas?

Comment: Works fine on mine.... have you cleared your cache? The trailing slash has been removed and the website runs without issue.