# How to remove / at the end of url by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Although I have tried hard, I could not be able to remove the auto-added "/" signs at the end of URLs. Please kindly help me. I can send the .htaccess file content of my site. I could not paste here. It gives error. Is there a way to attach it here for you?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ` I could not paste here` - why? just make it part of your question using proper `{}` formatting

Comment: Please Read [How to ask GOOD Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @marcin-orlowski Thanks, where shall I add it? Thanks in advance. {# BEGIN WpFastestCache
Redirect 301 /casino-reviews http://www.top10-casinosites.net/reviews/
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^top10-casinosites.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www\.top10\-casinosites\.net\/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
}

Comment: in question body, using proper formatting with `{}` button

Answer (score 0):

To enforce no trialing slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

[Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: Thanks a lot but my current htaccess file content is below. Where shall I add it? Thanks in advance. {}