# URL redirection issue on Apache

Tags: apache

I need to make a simple redirection on Apache. I have a site, let's call it www.example.com with a sub-folder "/dev".
What I want is to write a rule in Apache to redirect "www.example.com/dev/" to "www.example.com/dev" (without slash).

I tried the following but it doesn't work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dev/ /dev [R,L]
```

I guess this is due to the fact that the redirection is performed on www.example.com/dev/* whereas I want it only on "/dev"

Thanks for your help

Comment: You may want to refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement it but no success. I used the following :         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]