# HTACCESS no php or /

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following *htaccess* code. However this code means that my images or CSS are not loading, on the plus side it means that *.php* or the trailing / are needed like my client has asked for.

How can I make this work so that the images and the CSS and JS etc load correctly?

I would like the url to look like www.example.com/services or www.example.com/services/

currently google shows up both

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Wait can you clarify - do you want or _not_ want this to eliminate the `.php` extension and add a trailing slash? To get rid of those behaviors, comment out the last 4 lines.  It always helps with these questions to post examples of exact URLs which 1) the client requests 2) the file the server should return for that request 3) the URL you want to end up in the client browser after any redirection.

Comment: I have provided examples

Answer (score 0):

```
# enforce a trailing-slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# remove php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L,QSA]
```

**See also**

[Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

[Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)