# Adding trailing slash - Specific rules

Tags: .htaccess

I've got this setup:

```
RewriteRule ^brands$ brands/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^brands/$ /brands.php
RewriteRule ^brands/([A-ZÆØÅæøåa-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?manufacturers_name=$1&manufacturers_id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^brands/([0-9]+)$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$1 [L]
```

How would I fix it so there's always a trailing slash on this. Those specific URLs?

```
example.com/brands/brand-id
```

So if I went to either `example.com/brands/brand-id` OR `example.com/brands/brand-id/`, it'll work as having a trailing slash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: I only need it for those specific rules though, not the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your Rule with this

```
 RewriteRule ^brands/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$1 [L]
```

`/?` means that the `/` is optional in uri. Your rule will match both uri strings ending with or without a traling slash.

And to add the traling slash to specific  uris,put the following before your existing rules

```
RewriteRule ^brands/[0-9]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]
```

This will redirect `/brands/123` to `/brands/123/` .