# validating url without slash at endIndex

Tags: php, laravel

I am passing an URL with validating the slash in end index. But the problem is the slash may be present or not. so I need to pas only url wheather the slash in last index prsent or not.

The URL may be like

```
https://www.instagram.com/example/    (with slash endIndex) or
https://www.instagram.com/example     (without slash endIndex)
```

I need the URL as only

```
https://www.instagram.com/example    (without slash)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can adjust your [Apache Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url) or [Nginx Config](https://serverfault.com/questions/597302/removing-the-trailing-slash-from-a-url-with-nginx) to handle this for you. If you are using something locally like Laravel Valet with certain top-level domains you might need to make additional adjustments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

> Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: thanks , its worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following,

```
$string = "Remove Last Characterr";
substr($string, 0, -1);
substr_replace($string ,"",-1);
rtrim($string,'r');
```

Output: Remove Last Character

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicating canonical URLs which can downsize your SEO points, consider adding this rule to your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

This way you'll never have trailing slash in URL
Just different approach on solving your issues in question.