# Is it possible to create a redirect rule from URL with slash to one without it?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all URLs with a slash at the end to the corresponding URL without it. For example I need to redirect this URL:

> domain.com/category/subcategory/

to this URL:

> domain.com/category/subcategory

Or this URL:

> domain.com/category/

to this URL:

> domain.com/category

How can I do it with a .htaccess redirect rule? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: @Stoopkid yes sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```