# How to 301 redirect domain.com/ to domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

How to 301 redirect domain.com/ to domain.com so if someone open domain.com/ with / on end we need 301 redirect to domain.com without / on end, and this need affect on all pages:

domain.com/username/ to domain.com/username
domain.com/tag/lol/ to domain.com/tag/lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

**SOURCE:** [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: In your .htaccess file, below the RewriteEngine On, add the two lines