# Redirecting somehow added a trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, xampp

After using `header('Location:employees');exit;` after a `POST`, I was somehow redirected instead to `localhost/project_name/employees/`. Even if my `<a>` points to just `employees`

```
<a href="employees" role="button" class="col-1 my-1 mr-1 btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Employee</a>
```

I'm always redirected to `employees/`. This does not happen to the other links, and if I use `employee`, I'm being redirected correctly, no trailing slash being added. I suspect it is because of my `.htaccess`, but it does not affect other link.

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Even if I delete the contents, it still adds a trailing slash to `employees`. I already tried clearing the browser's data and opening it in another browser *(Microsoft Edge)*, still the same result.

I tried updating `htaccess` with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url), but still no success

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I also tried clearing all the contents of `employees.php` just to see if it because of my codes, but the problem still persist.

How can I prevent this from happening to the other links? I can't seem to reverse it, and the solution that I managed to find is to just change the name. Although it is not a problem, I want to know the cause of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments to answer.

None of the rules shown in question would add a trailing slash. It could be due to some code or Apache server directives.

To verify this, test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 3xx/4xx URLs it shows there.

Another thing to note is if your URI points to a real directory then Apache's `mod_dir` module adds a trailing directory and sends a `301` to clients for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this .htaccess: (backup your .htaccess first, then overwrite it with these lines)

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /project_name/$1 [L,R]
```

I just tested it on my server, it works!

Comment: The error went from **Object not found** to **Access Forbidden**

Comment: check the updated code, overwrite your .htaccess after you take a backup of it.

Comment: Well, I can't now open the links because they are now looking for the `.php` extension. And regarding the `employees`, it is still being redirected to `employees/`. One thing I noticed is that somehow, a folder named `employees` had been created

Comment: Wait, I'm actually being redirected to `localhost/employees` instead of `localhost/project_name/employees`. I tried using `/$1.php` instead of `/$1`, and it became `localhost/employees.php` while the other links does not have the `.php` extension when being redirected