# Remove trailing slash from url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

i have the following rewrite condition and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, all it takes is adding a trailing backslash to my url and the site breaks. I have seen several similar questions and answers but nothing works for me, mainly because i'm not familiar with htaccess.

How can i make make my url auto change from

http://localhost:8888/mysite/mylink/

to

http://localhost:8888/mysite/mylink

Iam using codeigniter and my application is still in localhost. Appreciate any help in this. Thanks.

Comment: You can find your answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Just change all your links without that slash at the end.