# Remove / sign from url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have spent 2hours online trying to get htaccess that will work for this, I want to redirect all `example.com/?s=keyword/` to `example.com/?s=keyword`

I want to remove the / Sign from the Url using .htaccess Please any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417551/4244684

Comment: Hey, the code there did not work for me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the trailing slash appears on the query string portion of the URL you need to use mod_rewrite and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. The `RewriteRule` (and `Redirect`, `RedirectMatch`) directives match against the URL-path only.

(The linked questions deal with the trailing slash on the URL-path, not the query string - this is a different problem.)

Try the following, at the very top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing WordPress directives (ie. before the `# BEGIN WordPress`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(\w+)/$
RewriteRule ^$ /?s=%1 [R,L]
```

`(\w+)` - This matches a single *keyword* of 1 or more "word" characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`). The `%1` backreference in the *substitution* string contains this *keyword*.

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive if this already exists in the WordPress block.

*Aside:* I do wonder *why* you would need to do this? Since this is part of the `s` URL parameter, this can (and should) already be handled by the PHP code?

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> Your code works but if there is spaces or `-` or `+` sign on the url, it will not redirect

Spaces can be encoded as `%20` or `+` in the query string. Providing you are OK with simply allowing `%`, rather than restricting this to specific URL encoded char(s), then you can modify the directives to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([\w%+-]+)/$
RewriteRule ^$ /?s=%1 [NE,R,L]
```

The `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive is required to prevent Apache from URL encoding the `%` (should it be present on the request) as `%25` (in the substitution). Essentially preventing Apache from doubly encoding the output URL. We assume that if there is already a `%` on the requested URL, it is already part of a valid URL-encoded sequence, eg. `%20` in the case of a space.

To allow *anything* then change the `RewriteCond` directive to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.+)/$
```

Note that this assumes that there is only a single URL parameter on this URL (as in your example).

Note also, that these are currently 302 (temporary) redirects. If this should be permanent then change `R` to `R=301`, but only once you have confirmed that it is working OK (to avoid caching issues).

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> what if I want to redirect a folder e.g `example.com/stack/?s=keyword/` to `example.com/stack/?s=keyword`

To redirect a specific subdirectory (or path-segment) as in this example then modify the `RewriteRule` directive to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^stack/$ /$0?s=%1 [NE,R,L]
```

If you needed to match either the root directory *or* this subdirectory then use:

```
RewriteRule ^(stack/)?$ /$1?s=%1 [NE,R,L]
```

To match *any* subdirectory *or* the root directory then use something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?$ /$1?s=%1 [NE,R,L]
```

Note that, in this example, the *subdirectory* is limited to "word" characters plus `-` (hyphen).

Comment: Your code works but if there is `spaces` or `-` or `+` sign on the url, it will not redirect

Comment: I've updated my answer. (Note that `+` is also decoded as a _space_ when used in the query string part of the URL.)

Comment: You are nearly there but all space in link changes to `%2520` Is there no way it can be replace with `+`

Comment: Thanks alot, I added `[L,R=301,NE]` which gave me what I was looking for. Thanks once again.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry forgot about that! The `NE` flag is required to prevent the `%` itself being URL-encoded in the target URL. I've updated my answer. It would be more tricky to replace `%20` with `+` as that would require an entirely separate rule (in fact, that would warrant its own question/answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: what if I want to redirect a folder e.g `example.com/stack/?s=keyword/` to `example.com/stack/?s=keyword`

Comment: Thank You so so much for your answers