# Proper .htaccess config for Next.js SSG

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, next.js

NextJS exports a static site with the following structure:

```
|-- index.html
|-- article.html
|-- tag.html
|-- article
|   |-- somearticle.html
|   \-- anotherarticle.html
\-- tag
    |-- tag1.html
    \-- tag2.html
```

I'm using an .htaccess file to hide the .html extensions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Everything works flawlessly, EXCEPT:

- If I follow a link to `domain/article` it displays the article.html page, but my address bar shows `domain/article` <--Good.
- If I refresh, I get sent to address: `domain/article/` (note trailing slash) which lists the contents of the article directory <--Bad (same thing with Tag)
- Similarly, manually typing in `domain/article` takes me to `domain/article/` instead of showing `article.html` without the `.html` extension.

So...

- How do I fix this?
- Is this an .htaccess issue?
- A nextjs config issue?
- (Wouldn't it be    better for NextJS to create a `article\index.html` instead of a file in the root directory?)

---

[`exportTrailingSlash`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash)

I tried playing around with `exportTrailingSlash` which seems related, but this created other problems like always having a trailing slash at the end of all my links:

Eg: if I go to `domain/article/somearticle` and hit refresh, something (.httaccess?) is adding a `/` to the end to give me `domain/article/somearticle/` not horrible, just not very clean and inconsistent...

***Edit:*** Actually, it's a little more horrible, because sometimes we get a trailing slash, sometimes we don't on the nextjs links... must be something about how I'm using `<Link />` but I can't figure that out.

Regardless, NONE of the `.htaccess` rules I've tried successfully remove the trailing slash all the time every time...

---

More details:

In my next app, I have folder:

```
/articles/
   [slug].js
   index.js
```

In various pages, I use nextJS Link component:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

<Link href="/articles" as="/articles">
            <a>Articles</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you request `/article` and `/article` exists as a physical directory then Apache's mod_dir, will (by default) append the trailing slash in order to "fix" the URL. This is achieved with a 301 permanent redirect - so it will be cached by the browser.

Although having a physical directory with the same basename as a file and using extensionless URLs creates an ambiguity. eg. Is `/article` supposed to access the directory `/article/` or the file `/article.html`. You don't seem to want to allow direct access to directories anyway, so that would seem to resolve that ambiguity.

To prevent Apache mod_dir appending the trailing slash to directories we need to disable the `DirectorySlash`. For example:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

But as mentioned, if you have previously visited `/article` then the redirect to `/article/` will have been cached by the browser - so you'll need to clear the browser cache before this will be effective.

Since you are removing the file extension you also need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled, otherwise, mod_negotiation will issue an internal subrequest for the underlying file, and potentially conflict with mod_rewrite. MultiViews is disabled by default, although some shared hosts do enable it for some reason. From the output you are getting it doesn't look like MultiViews is enabled, but better to be sure...

```
# Ensure that MutliViews is disabled
Options -MultiViews
```

However, if you need to be able to access the directory itself then you will need to manually append the trailing slash with an internal rewrite. Although this does not seem to be a requirement here. You should, however, ensure that directory listings are disabled:

```
# Disable directory listings
Options -Indexes
```

Attempting to access any directory (that does not ultimately map to a file - see below) and does not contain a `DirectoryIndex` document will return a 403 Forbidden response, instead of a directory listing.

Note that the only difference that could occur between following a link to `domain/article`, refreshing the page and manually typing `domain/article` is *caching...* either by the browser or any intermediary proxy caches. (Unless you have JavaScript that intercepts the click event on the anchor?!)

You do still need to rewrite requests from `/foo` to `/foo.html` OR `/foo` to `/foo/index.html` (see below), depending on how you have configured your site. Although it would be preferable that you choose one or the other, rather than both (as you seem to imply could be the case).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
> ```

It is unclear how this is seemingly "working" for you currently - unless you are seeing a cached response? When you request `/article`, the first condition fails because this exists as a physical directory and the rule is not processed. Even with MultiViews enabled, mod_dir will take priority and append the trailing slash.

The second condition that checks the existence of the `.html` file isn't necessarily checking the same file that is being rewritten to. eg. If you request `/foo/bar`, where `/foo.html` exists, but there is no physical directory `/foo` then the `RewriteCond` directive checks for the existence of `/foo.html` - which is successful, but the request is internally rewritten to `/foo/bar.html` (from the captured `RewriteRule` *pattern*) - this results in an internal rewrite loop and a 500 error response being returned to the client. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the [following ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error) that goes into more detail behind what is actually happening here.

We can also make a further optimisation if we assume that any URL that contains what looks like a file extension (eg. your static resources `.css`, `.js` and image files) should be ignored, otherwise we are performing filesystem checks on every request, which is relatively expensive.

So, in order to map (internally rewrite) requests of the form `/article` to `/article.html` and `/article/somearticle` to `/article/somearticle.html` you would need to modify the above rule to read something like:

```
# Rewrite /foo to /foo.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

There is no need to backslash escape a literal dot in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* - the dot carries no special meaning here; it's not a regex.

Then, to handle requests of the form `/foo` that should map to `/foo/index.html` you can do something like the following:

```
# Rewrite /foo to /foo/index.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]
```

Ordinarily, you would allow mod_dir to serve the `DirectoryIndex` (eg. `index.html`), but having omitted the trailing slash from the directory, this can be problematic.

#### Summary

Bringing the above points together, we have:

```
# Disable directory indexes and MultiViews
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

# Prevent mod_dir appending a slash to directory requests
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite /foo to /foo.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# Otherwise, rewrite /foo to /foo/index.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]
```

This could be further optimised, depending on your site structure and whether you are adding any more directives to the `.htaccess` file. For example:

1. you could check for file extensions on the requested URL at the top of the file to prevent any further processing. The `RewriteRule` regex on each subsequent rule could then be "simplified".
2. Requests that include a trailing slash could be blocked or redirected (to remove the trailing slash).
3. If the request is for a `.html` file then redirect to the extensionless URL. This is made slightly more complicated if you are dealing with both `/foo.html` and `/foo/index.html`. But this is only really necessary if you are *changing* an existing URL structure.

For example, implementing #1 and #2 above, would enable the directives to be written like so:

```
# Disable directory indexes and MultiViews
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

# Prevent mod_dir appending a slash to directory requests
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Prevent any further processing if the URL already ends with a file extension
RewriteRule \.\w{2,4}$ - [L]

# Redirect any requests to remove a trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite /foo to /foo.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]

# Otherwise, rewrite /foo to /foo/index.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1/index.html [L]
```

Always test with a 302 (temporary) redirect before changing to a 301 (permanent) redirect in order to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Excellent! I've learned something here. Specifically `DirectorySlash` is new to me. I don't have time to test all this out till tomorrow, but appreciate the thorough response

Comment: Just to add... you also need to make sure that MultiViews is disabled for these directives to work as intended. (From your output, I think it probably is already.) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Super thorough. And although I still haven't actually solved my problem, the detailed explanation gives me lots to go on... so I'm optimistic.

Comment: Ack sorry - had life come up the bounty was auto-awarded at 1/2 before I could get back here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found the Summary answers still did not work for me until I added `RewriteEngine On` to my .htaccess file.

Comment: @ChrisL8 Ah, thanks! That was an accidental omission! The `RewriteEngine On` directive is required otherwise the mod_rewrite directives will simply be ignored. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> - (Wouldn't it be better for NextJS to create a `article\index.html` instead of a file in the root directory?)

Yes! And Next [can do that](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap) for you:

> It is possible to configure Next.js to export pages as index.html
> files and require trailing slashes, `/about` becomes `/about/index.html`
> and is routable via `/about/`. This was the default behavior prior to
> Next.js 9.
>
> To switch back and add a trailing slash, open `next.config.js` and
> enable the `exportTrailingSlash` config:
>
> `module.exports = {   exportTrailingSlash: true, }`

Comment: Not sure how I missed `exportPathMap` looking into it now. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer if it ends up working for you.

Comment: So I revisited `exportTrailingSlash` and this looks to work, EXCEPT when I got to `domain/article/somearticle` and hit refresh, something (.httaccess?) is adding a `/` to the end to give me `domain/article/somearticle/` not horrible, just not very clean...

Comment: You may need another htaccess rule to remove trailing slash for directories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264788/1174966

Comment: @Trees4theForest Does `/article/somearticle` also map to a physical directory? (This is not indicated in the file structure you posted.)

Comment: @MrWhite so... depends? If next.js flag `exportTrailingSlash` is enabled, then we get `/article/somearticle/index.html` otherwise it's `/article/somearticle.html`

Comment: @jdaz I've tried every combination of .htaccess and no love... at least not consistently.

Comment: Hmm. What about going back to your original config (no `exportTrailingSlash`) and use the slightly different htaccess on [this page](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/). It uses the regex `^([^\.]+)$` compared to your `^(.*)$`, which may be the issue.