# Proper .htaccess settings for Next.js SSG catch all routes

Tags: .htaccess, next.js, dynamic-import, ssg

I've build a website, using Next.js and SSG - Static Site Generation.
I'm serving the website on an Apache server and, therefore, because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799999/proper-htaccess-config-for-next-js-ssg), I'm using the following .htaccess configuration:

```
# Disable directory indexes and MultiViews
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

# Prevent mod_dir appending a slash to directory requests
DirectorySlash Off

# Rewrite /foo to /foo.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# Otherwise, rewrite /foo to /foo/index.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]

# Handling 404
ErrorDocument 404 /my-custom-404.html
```

And it's been working perfectly.

But recently, there was a need for an admin page, the usual CRUD. I've developed it without SSG in mind (because there were actually no need for it), created my own custom router and used [Next.js's catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) to handle all content of this admin page, which I called *dashboard*.

So, on my built website, I have a whole bunch of `page.html` files, and a `/dashboard/[[...dashboard]].html` file, which is the CRUD itself (all subpages and contents are imported dynamically) - and, therefore, every single link starting with `/dashboard` will be handled via that file.

**So, the problem is:** navigating through the links on the website and into the *dashboard*, everything works perfectly. But if I try to **directly** access any link within `/dashboard` (including itself, and subroutes: `/dashboard/users`, for instance), it simply does not work. With the provided `.htaccess` configuration, it goes straight to 404.

I've tried a few different configurations added to .htaccess, but none have worked so far (either it still goes straight to 404, or the browser shows the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dashboard/$1
RewriteRule (.*) /dashboard/[[...dashboard]].html [L]
```

This one almost worked... but the dashboard itself does not do anything (no subpages are ever rendered):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*dashboard*.
RewriteRule (.*) /dashboard/[[...dashboard]].html [L]
```

**Important note:** this whole thing works perfectly on the local dev server.

If anyone has any tip on how I can sort this thing out, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it, at least on an acceptable level.

As I mentioned on the question, this was almost working (no sub page was ever rendered, but at least the browser was correctly redirecting to the dashboard):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*dashboard*.
RewriteRule (.*) /dashboard/[[...dashboard]].html [L]
```

No page was ever rendered, because I was using Next.js's [withRouter/useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) to inform my custom router of the current route (via `router.asPath`), and when the above rule as met, router.asPath was set to `dashboard/[[...dashboard]].html`.
So, I wrote a small test to redirect any access with that asPath to my entrypoint. Basically:

```
if(router.asPath.contains('[[...dashboard]]')
    router.push('/dashboard')
```

But, another problem arouse...
The first problem was solved: trying to access any dashboard routes directly was working, but navigating through the website (links) was not. After an arduous and long process of trial and error, I found out that my previous .htaccess rule was preventing my client-side code to request my [[...dashboard]].html file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*dashboard*.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\[\[\.\.\.dashboard\]\])
RewriteRule (.*) /dashboard/[[...dashboard]].html?p=$1 [L]
```

Basically:

- If my request URI contains 'dashboard'
- AND if that same request does not contain [[...dashboard]]
- THEN I rewrite it to the dashboard file

Hope this might help someone someday!