# Apache redirect for adding missing .html at the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect any request that doesn't have the last segment contain a dot to .html

examples:

```
/travels/
/travels.html
/travels/categories/new-zealand
/travels/categories/main.js
```

Line 2 and 4 should not be redirected while line 1 and 3 should be redirected to:

```
/travels.html
/travels/categories/new-zealand.html
```

I already have this regex that seems to work for capturing: `^(https?:\/\/.+(\..+)*\/)?[^\s.]+$`

How do I exactly make this redirect happen? I have a vserver with an apache werbserver that is running and mod_rewrite is enabled. How exactly would the rewrite statement look and where do I put it? If I put it in a .htaccess file, where do I keep that? Inside the root of the page or anywhere?

Comment: This answer to this qestion also works for my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62885271/5211055

Answer (score 1):

You can not match against host and https header in the rule's pattern. You can only match against URL path in a `RewriteRule` . To check the host and https header you need to use `RewriteConds`

```
 RewriteEngine on
# URL scheme is HTTPS
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
# Host is www.example.com or example.com
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
#URL path is /travels/ then redirect the request to /travels.html
 RewriteRule ^/?travels/$ /travels.html [R,L]
```

This will redirect `https://example.com/travels/`
to `https://example.com/travels.html`  . This changes the URL in your browser from old to the new one, if you want the redirection to happen internally then just remove the `R` flag.

Comment: how can I make that last RewriteRule dynamically that it works for any URL? for example it should also turn `/foo/bar` into `/foo/bar.html` and `/foo` into `/foo.html`

Comment: @ivsterr Just replace the rule with `RewriteRule ^/?(travels|foobar|foobar2)/$ /$1.html [R,L]`

Comment: But that is still not dynamic is it? I would have to add every page that I ever create

Comment: Also: do i place the .htaccess next to my index.html or where do I put it? I am trying to get it to work with`/travels` redirecting to `/travels.html`

Comment: @ivsterr yes this is not dynamic . You have to manually add other paths to it. You can also use a dynamic pattern like `^/?(.+)/$` but since it catches all requests it can conflict with your other rules and URIs if you use a dynamic one.