Hosting Nextjs on hostinger
I want to host the Nextjs website on Hostinger so I export Nextjs as static in (out) directory using output: 'export' in next config
I uploaded the static files on hostinger and it worked.
but once you refresh any page except the home page, Hostinger can't serve the page and shows a 404 page
So what is the issue here and how can I debug it

You need to create .htaccess file in root of your project. and paste lines answered in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799999/proper-htaccess-config-for-next-js-ssg

I found the issue which is url doesn't explicitly contain .html at the end
because when the route, for example, is /test, apache on Hostinger is looking for a directory call test and has index.html file but instead nextjs export html files with their names test.html so apache can't find this directory and return 404.
the solution is to create .htaccess file inside public_html directory and configure the apache to serve HTML files by their names
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L] 

