# Facing issue with wordpress url

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am facing a issue with my wordpress blog and tried alog but did not found any solution. Actually I want to run my wordpress blog without slash at the end but when I am removing slash at the end of url its showing 403 error Forbidden. Please help me to resolve this issue.

https://www.test.com/blog  ==> Not working (Preferable)
https://www.test.com/blog/  ==> Working

screenshot:- https://prnt.sc/u6rqtp

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url .

Comment: Show your apache config and any .htaccess files, or web/nginx config

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of: [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: Given url is not able to resolve my problem

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`   

this is my htaccess