# SilverStripe 4 - Remove slash at the end of the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've been trying for some time to delete the slash at the end of the URL link, but it doesn't work. I searched a lot of examples but none of them solve my problem.

I'm using Silverstripe 4 and currently running on a local server.
I have to remove the slash for SEO reasons.

**My current URL is:**

```
www.example.com/
 
// Need to be like below 

www.example.com
```

**I try via htaccess**

Exampe from [stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417551/2040496)

I put in /public/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]
```

and when i visit homepage slash is there at the end.

**I try via code in **SiteTree****

```
public function Link($action = null)
 {
   return rtrim(parent::Link($action), '/');
 }
```

Above code remove slash at the end from all pages but on home page still there.

```
www.example.com/about-us (here removed)
www.exaple.com/ (here exists)
```

**And also try via config file**

```
Director::config()->set('alternate_base_url', rtrim(Environment::getEnv('SS_BASE_URL'), '/'));
```

But again slash exists at the end of the url on homepage.

Does someone have solution for this? Thanks!

**Here is my full htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Turn off index.php handling requests to the homepage fixes issue in apache >=2.4
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        DirectorySlash On
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On

    # Enable HTTP Basic authentication workaround for PHP running in CGI mode
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Deny access to potentially sensitive files and folders
    RewriteRule ^vendor(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^\.env - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule silverstripe-cache(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule composer\.(json|lock) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule (error|silverstripe|debug)\.log - [F,L,NC]

    # Process through SilverStripe if no file with the requested name exists.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* index.php


    # REMOVE SLASH AT THE END OF THE URL

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> www.example.com/
>  
> // Need to be like below 
>
> www.example.com
> ```

What you are trying to do is not possible! You are trying to remove the slash at the *start* of the URL-path, immediately after the hostname. This is not the same as the slash at the *end* of the URL-path.

There is *always* a slash at the start of the URL-path, even if you don't always see this in the browser's address bar (the browser often "prettifies" the URL you *see* in the address bar). This is necessary in order to form a valid HTTP request.

Whether you request `www.example.com` (no slash) or `www.example.com/` (with slash), the user-agent/browser actually makes the exact same request to the server, ie. `www.example.com/` (note that Google Chrome never displays the trailing slash after the hostname in the address bar, aka "omnibox", even if you type it in). If you look at the first line of the HTTP request headers you will see something like the following in both cases:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Note the first slash (delimited by *spaces*) - that represents the URL-path. It is not valid to have *nothing* here (eg. `GET  HTTP/1.1` is not a valid HTTP request).

This is different to removing the slash at the end of the URL-path, eg. `www.example.com/about-us/` to `www.example.com/about-us`. In this case the trailing slash is just another character. (Although there is naturally a complication when the URL-path maps to a physical directory since mod_dir will (by default) always append a trailing slash in this instance.)

See also [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/35646/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters Stack for more detail:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Further reference:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2

---

> I try via htaccess

Attempting to remove the slash from the start of the URL-path will result in a redirect loop since the user-agent will *correct* the request each time. For the request to have reached your server then there must have been a slash at the start of the URL-path (ie. after the hostname).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
> ```

The homepage, ie. document root, is a *directory* so the *condition* fails and the rule is not processed.

But the *pattern* `^(.*)/$` will only successfully match a non-empty URL-path. And `/$1` naturally redirects with a slash prefix. To omit the slash you would need to do something like this:

```
# DON'T DO THIS
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com [R,L]
```

But this is *nonsense* and will result in a redirect loop, for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer i understand what you write. Slash at end of the domain is requered by HTTP for making new request. If i omit it HTTP will automaticly add it right? But i check on google chrome to visit google.com and in browser url bar there is no slash, i check on another popular also does not have slash.

Comment: @Ivan "If i omit it HTTP will automaticly add it right?" - If you omit the slash after the hostname then the _user-agent_ essentially fixes it before making the HTTP request (but you don't necessarily see it in the browser address bar). "i check on google chrome to visit google.com and in browser url bar there is no slash" - Google Chrome does not show the slash after the hostname in the address bar for _any_ domain. It also doesn't show the protocol or common subdomains like www (but that doesn't mean they are not there). Google Chrome "prettifies" the URL you see in the address bar.

Comment: @Ivan For example: navigate to [`https://www.example.com/`](https://www.example.com/). What do you see in Google Chrome's address bar (aka "omnibox")? Then click on the address bar, what do you see now? If you navigate to the root of your domain; what do you see? Do you see a trailing slash after the hostname??

Comment: you are right for. Now i understend.