# How to remove the slash at the end of the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url

My problem is that when I visit my site I always see slash end of the url.

How do I disable that slash that's being added in .htaccess. Thanks!

www.example.com/products/type/name/

Comment: Is /name/ an existent directory?

Comment: it is the last directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing trailing slash from ALL URLs in site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081146/removing-trailing-slash-from-all-urls-in-site)